# Tomcat security manager - c3p0 and hibernate

Tags: java, mysql, security, hibernate, tomcat

I am using a Tomcat security enabled server, and Hibernate3 with c3p0.
Here are my policies in catalina.policy (I found these lines on the net and changed a bit):

```
grant codeBase "file:${catalina.base}/webapps/omiccir/-" 
{

    /////////////// FilePermission ////////// 
    permission java.io.FilePermission "${catalina.home}/log4j.properties", "read"; 
    permission java.io.FilePermission "${catalina.home}/logging.properties", "read"; 
    permission java.io.FilePermission "${catalina.home}/hibernate.properties", "read"; 
    permission java.io.FilePermission "${java.home}/lib/xerces.properties", "read"; 
    //permission java.io.FilePermission "opproject.log", "write"; 
    //permission java.io.FilePermission "${catalina.home}/Onepoint Project Home/-", "read, write, delete"; 


    // FIXME line below is VERY system specific, take care! 
    permission java.io.FilePermission "/tmp/tomcat6-tmp", "write"; 


    // thought it was java.io.tmpdir, but may be wrong // 
    permission java.io.FilePermission "${java.io.tmpdir}/tomcat6-tmp", "write"; 


    /////////////// LoggingPermission ////////// 
    permission java.util.logging.LoggingPermission "control"; 


    /////////////// PropertyPermission ////////// 
    permission java.util.PropertyPermission "org.apache.cxf.Logger", "read"; 
    permission java.util.PropertyPermission "org.apache.commons.logging.*", "read"; 
    permission java.util.PropertyPermission "log4j.*", "read"; 
    permission java.util.PropertyPermission "logger.home", "read"; 
    permission java.util.PropertyPermission "user.*", "read"; 
    permission java.util.PropertyPermission "org.apache.xerces.*", "read"; 
    permission java.util.PropertyPermission "ONEPOINT_PROJECT_HOME", "read"; 
    permission java.util.PropertyPermission "com.sun.xml.bind.v2.*", "read"; 
    permission java.util.PropertyPermission "com.sun.xml.bind.v2.runtime.JAXBContextImpl.fastBoot", "write"; 
    permission java.util.PropertyPermission "cglib.debugLocation", "read"; 
    permission java.util.PropertyPermission "org.dom4j.*", "read"; 
    permission java.util.PropertyPermission "c3p0.*", "read"; 
    permission java.util.PropertyPermission "net.sf.ehcache.*", "read"; 
    permission java.util.PropertyPermission "ANTLR_DO_NOT_EXIT", "read"; 
    permission java.util.PropertyPermission "ANTLR_USE_DIRECT_CLASS_LOADING", "read"; 


    /////////////// RuntimePermission ////////// 
    permission java.lang.RuntimePermission "accessClassInPackage.sun.jdbc.odbc"; 
    permission java.lang.RuntimePermission "accessClassInPackage.org.apache.tomcat.util.http"; 
    permission java.lang.RuntimePermission "accessClassInPackage.org.apache.tomcat.util.http.res"; 
    permission java.lang.RuntimePermission "accessClassInPackage.sun.reflect.generics.reflectiveObjects"; 
    permission java.lang.RuntimePermission "accessClassInPackage.sun.util.calendar"; 
    permission java.lang.RuntimePermission "defineClassInPackage.java.lang"; 
    permission java.lang.RuntimePermission "getClassLoader"; 
    permission java.lang.RuntimePermission "getProtectionDomain"; 



    /////////////// ReflectPermission ////////// 
    permission java.lang.reflect.ReflectPermission "suppressAccessChecks"; 

    permission java.net.SocketPermission "*", "resolve"; 
    permission java.net.SocketPermission "localhost:5432", "connect,resolve"; 

    //What is this line??
    //permission java.net.SocketPermission "www.onepoint.at:80", "connect,resolve"; 


    /////////////// MBean...Permission ///////// 
    permission javax.management.MBeanServerPermission "createMBeanServer"; 
    permission javax.management.MBeanPermission "com.mchange.v2.c3p0.*", "*"; 
    permission javax.management.MBeanTrustPermission "register"; 


    permission java.util.PropertyPermission "*", "read,write"; 
}
```

I don't know what is wrong, but it seems that there is a problem with c3p0, and this goes away when I use Tomcat without a security manager.

This is my stack trace:

```
org.apache.jasper.JasperException: org.hibernate.exception.GenericJDBCException: Cannot open connection
    org.apache.jasper.servlet.JspServletWrapper.handleJspException(JspServletWrapper.java:491)
    org.apache.jasper.servlet.JspServletWrapper.service(JspServletWrapper.java:419)
    org.apache.jasper.servlet.JspServlet.serviceJspFile(JspServlet.java:313)
    org.apache.jasper.servlet.JspServlet.service(JspServlet.java:260)
    javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:717)
    sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:39)
    sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:25)
    java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:597)
    org.apache.catalina.security.SecurityUtil$1.run(SecurityUtil.java:269)
    java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    javax.security.auth.Subject.doAsPrivileged(Subject.java:517)
    org.apache.catalina.security.SecurityUtil.execute(SecurityUtil.java:301)
    org.apache.catalina.security.SecurityUtil.doAsPrivilege(SecurityUtil.java:162)

root cause

org.hibernate.exception.GenericJDBCException: Cannot open connection
    org.hibernate.exception.SQLStateConverter.handledNonSpecificException(SQLStateConverter.java:140)
    org.hibernate.exception.SQLStateConverter.convert(SQLStateConverter.java:128)
    org.hibernate.exception.JDBCExceptionHelper.convert(JDBCExceptionHelper.java:66)
    org.hibernate.exception.JDBCExceptionHelper.convert(JDBCExceptionHelper.java:52)
    org.hibernate.jdbc.ConnectionManager.openConnection(ConnectionManager.java:449)
    org.hibernate.jdbc.ConnectionManager.getConnection(ConnectionManager.java:167)
    org.hibernate.jdbc.JDBCContext.connection(JDBCContext.java:160)
    org.hibernate.transaction.JDBCTransaction.begin(JDBCTransaction.java:81)
    org.hibernate.impl.SessionImpl.beginTransaction(SessionImpl.java:1473)
    sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:39)
    sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:25)
    java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:597)
    org.hibernate.context.ThreadLocalSessionContext$TransactionProtectionWrapper.invoke(ThreadLocalSessionContext.java:345)
    $Proxy4.beginTransaction(Unknown Source)
    ir.omicc.classes.Publisher.getTop5News(Publisher.java:100)
    org.apache.jsp.index_jsp._jspService(index_jsp.java:229)
    org.apache.jasper.runtime.HttpJspBase.service(HttpJspBase.java:70)
    javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:717)
    org.apache.jasper.servlet.JspServletWrapper.service(JspServletWrapper.java:377)
    org.apache.jasper.servlet.JspServlet.serviceJspFile(JspServlet.java:313)
    org.apache.jasper.servlet.JspServlet.service(JspServlet.java:260)
    javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:717)
    sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:39)
    sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:25)
    java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:597)
    org.apache.catalina.security.SecurityUtil$1.run(SecurityUtil.java:269)
    java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    javax.security.auth.Subject.doAsPrivileged(Subject.java:517)
    org.apache.catalina.security.SecurityUtil.execute(SecurityUtil.java:301)
    org.apache.catalina.security.SecurityUtil.doAsPrivilege(SecurityUtil.java:162)

root cause

java.sql.SQLException: Connections could not be acquired from the underlying database!
    com.mchange.v2.sql.SqlUtils.toSQLException(SqlUtils.java:106)
    com.mchange.v2.c3p0.impl.C3P0PooledConnectionPool.checkoutPooledConnection(C3P0PooledConnectionPool.java:529)
    com.mchange.v2.c3p0.impl.AbstractPoolBackedDataSource.getConnection(AbstractPoolBackedDataSource.java:128)
    org.hibernate.connection.C3P0ConnectionProvider.getConnection(C3P0ConnectionProvider.java:78)
    org.hibernate.jdbc.ConnectionManager.openConnection(ConnectionManager.java:446)
    org.hibernate.jdbc.ConnectionManager.getConnection(ConnectionManager.java:167)
    org.hibernate.jdbc.JDBCContext.connection(JDBCContext.java:160)
    org.hibernate.transaction.JDBCTransaction.begin(JDBCTransaction.java:81)
    org.hibernate.impl.SessionImpl.beginTransaction(SessionImpl.java:1473)
    sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:39)
    sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:25)
    java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:597)
    org.hibernate.context.ThreadLocalSessionContext$TransactionProtectionWrapper.invoke(ThreadLocalSessionContext.java:345)
    $Proxy4.beginTransaction(Unknown Source)
    ir.omicc.classes.Publisher.getTop5News(Publisher.java:100)
    org.apache.jsp.index_jsp._jspService(index_jsp.java:229)
    org.apache.jasper.runtime.HttpJspBase.service(HttpJspBase.java:70)
    javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:717)
    org.apache.jasper.servlet.JspServletWrapper.service(JspServletWrapper.java:377)
    org.apache.jasper.servlet.JspServlet.serviceJspFile(JspServlet.java:313)
    org.apache.jasper.servlet.JspServlet.service(JspServlet.java:260)
    javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:717)
    sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:39)
    sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:25)
    java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:597)
    org.apache.catalina.security.SecurityUtil$1.run(SecurityUtil.java:269)
    java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    javax.security.auth.Subject.doAsPrivileged(Subject.java:517)
    org.apache.catalina.security.SecurityUtil.execute(SecurityUtil.java:301)
    org.apache.catalina.security.SecurityUtil.doAsPrivilege(SecurityUtil.java:162)

root cause

com.mchange.v2.resourcepool.CannotAcquireResourceException: A ResourcePool could not acquire a resource from its primary factory or source.
    com.mchange.v2.resourcepool.BasicResourcePool.awaitAvailable(BasicResourcePool.java:1319)
    com.mchange.v2.resourcepool.BasicResourcePool.prelimCheckoutResource(BasicResourcePool.java:557)
    com.mchange.v2.resourcepool.BasicResourcePool.checkoutResource(BasicResourcePool.java:477)
    com.mchange.v2.c3p0.impl.C3P0PooledConnectionPool.checkoutPooledConnection(C3P0PooledConnectionPool.java:525)
    com.mchange.v2.c3p0.impl.AbstractPoolBackedDataSource.getConnection(AbstractPoolBackedDataSource.java:128)
    org.hibernate.connection.C3P0ConnectionProvider.getConnection(C3P0ConnectionProvider.java:78)
    org.hibernate.jdbc.ConnectionManager.openConnection(ConnectionManager.java:446)
    org.hibernate.jdbc.ConnectionManager.getConnection(ConnectionManager.java:167)
    org.hibernate.jdbc.JDBCContext.connection(JDBCContext.java:160)
    org.hibernate.transaction.JDBCTransaction.begin(JDBCTransaction.java:81)
    org.hibernate.impl.SessionImpl.beginTransaction(SessionImpl.java:1473)
    sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:39)
    sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:25)
    java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:597)
    org.hibernate.context.ThreadLocalSessionContext$TransactionProtectionWrapper.invoke(ThreadLocalSessionContext.java:345)
    $Proxy4.beginTransaction(Unknown Source)
    ir.omicc.classes.Publisher.getTop5News(Publisher.java:100)
    org.apache.jsp.index_jsp._jspService(index_jsp.java:229)
    org.apache.jasper.runtime.HttpJspBase.service(HttpJspBase.java:70)
    javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:717)
    org.apache.jasper.servlet.JspServletWrapper.service(JspServletWrapper.java:377)
    org.apache.jasper.servlet.JspServlet.serviceJspFile(JspServlet.java:313)
    org.apache.jasper.servlet.JspServlet.service(JspServlet.java:260)
    javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:717)
    sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:39)
    sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:25)
    java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:597)
    org.apache.catalina.security.SecurityUtil$1.run(SecurityUtil.java:269)
    java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    javax.security.auth.Subject.doAsPrivileged(Subject.java:517)
    org.apache.catalina.security.SecurityUtil.execute(SecurityUtil.java:301)
    org.apache.catalina.security.SecurityUtil.doAsPrivilege(SecurityUtil.java:162)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Going by the stacktraces in the exception, it looks like the failure is due the inability to find a physical connection in the connection pool, after waiting for a sufficient period of time. The reason for this could be deduced to the following two permissions granted in the policy:

```
permission java.net.SocketPermission "*", "resolve"; 
permission java.net.SocketPermission "localhost:5432", "connect,resolve";
```

The "connect" action has been allowed only to the localhost, and only at port 5432. If this is not the database server, then it is most likely that physical connections were not created. You'll need to grant the appropriate permission (SocketPermission) for the required actions (connect,resolve) to the database server.

Note - the exception stack traces do not indicate that a permission was denied when creating the physical connection. This was deduced; you might want to look for other stack traces or other log files, or enable a lower level of logging, to determine if there are other failures.

**Related:**

1. [c3p0 pool cannot establish a coonection. How to debug this?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2166460/c3p0-pool-cannot-establish-a-coonection-how-to-debug-this). The tips (especially the third one) in the answer to this question, would go some way in resolving this issue.

Comment: yepp, that was it, i changed the port to 3306 and the error changed. then add     permission java.lang.RuntimePermission "accessClassInPackage.org.apache.coyote"; and that did the trick. thnx

Comment: but there is another problem now , when i eliminate this line permission java.util.PropertyPermission "*", "read,write"; the webpage shows nothing! not even a stacktrace to debug

Comment: @dave, that might be a required permission. There might be bits and pieces of code that would execute `System.setProperty(...)` and `System.getProperty(...)` commands. I'm not sure if any of the dependent libraries actually invoke the `AccessController.doPrivileged(...)` method, for that would aided in determining which codesources should have which permissions. You could try using the `-Djava.security.debug=access,failure` JVM arguments in the startup script to figure out failures. I'll warn you that the output could be a lot of lines to parse.

Answer (score 1):

give the socket permission to your jdbc driver

> grant codeBase
>   "jar:file:${catalina.home}${file.separator}webapps${file.separator}strutsspringjpaexample${file.separator}WEB-INF${file.separator}lib${file.separator}mysql-*.jar!/-"
>   {     permission java.net.SocketPermission "localhost:3306","connect"; };